# How to change preview of Play Store app when sharing on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, preview

I have changed icon and screenshot of my game in Google Play Developer Console and it's showing correctly at Play Store. But when I'm trying to share Play Store link on Facebook, preview coming with an old icon and screenshots.

How can I update this preview to latest version of app?

Comment: Try if re-scraping it via the debug tool helps. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

Did you just recently change it? A lot of googles hosted services are cloud (slow moving big data) and take a few hours or so to refresh everywhere.

Comment: No, changed about 2 days ago